# "И так" в значении "уже в состоянии"

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия

Не уверен в правильности своего русского, но может ли "и так" в литературной речи использоваться в качестве "уже"? Можно примеры откуда-то? 
Пример:

```
- Посоли суп.
- Суп и так соленый!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— Посоли суп.

— Суп и так соленый!

1) Здесь такое значение. *Суп и **так** уже* **(без дополнительной порции соли)** *соленый,* *а ты его еще хочешь посолить.*

И — усилительная частица, ТАК — указательное местоимение. Значение указательного местоимения **определяется по ситуации**.

2) Наречие *УЖЕ* можно  добавить, но не обязательно, оно не заменяет сочетание *И ТАК*, что видно из следующего сравнения:

***Суп и так уже  соленый* (в нем достаточно соли). *Суп уже соленый* (его уже посолили).**

3) Это **разные ситуации,** например.

Он попробовал суп и просит его еще посолить. Она возражает, ей кажется, что он уже соленый.

Он не пробовал суп, но просит его посолить. Она говорит, что уже солила суп.

Надо добавить, что в первом случае выражен определенный **эмоциональный протест** вида "и так уже (), а ты ещё..."

4) Другие примеры:

*И **так** (**без обогревателя**) жарко, а ты еще обогреватель включил.*

***И так уже*** все устали (без уборки), а ты еще уборку затеял.

Answer (score 0):

> может ли "и так" в литературной речи использоваться в качестве "Уже"?

Строго говоря - нет. "И так" в подобных конструкциях означает "без дополнительных действий", а это весьма слабый синоним для "уже". Лишь в отдельных случаях значения достаточно близки.

> суп и так соленый

Сказать так безусловно можно. Но вашем примере значение "и так" не является заменой "уже".

Сравните:
**компьютер уже работает** - включен и/или исправен.
**компьютер и так работает** - не нуждается в обслуживании.

Comment: "Безусловно" у вас вроде вводное слово. Значение ***безоговорочно*** как-то не подходит.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *"Безусловно" у вас вроде вводное слово. Значение безоговорочно как-то не подходит.* Я имел в виду именно "безоговорочно". А почему оно не подходит-то?! ***Сказать так можно безусловно*** - так понятнее?!. Ели честно, то мне случалось и раньше спорить на тему "наречие или вводное"  в моих текстах. Но там действительно были пограничные случаи... Тут я даже подумать не мог, что так будет воспринято.

Comment: То есть смысл не близкий к "конечно"? Сложно воспринимать в значении наречия в данном случае, но верю, что вы его имели в виду. *Сказать так можно безусловно - так понятнее?!* Немного понятнее, но, честно, не совсем. :)